# nested JSON to CSV using python

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing, nested

I'm new to python and I've got a large JSON file that I need to convert to CSV - below is a sample

```
{
"status":"success",
"Name":"Theresa May",
"Location":"87654321",
"AccountCategory":"Business",
"AccountType":"Current",
"TicketNo":"12345-12",
"AvailableBal":"12775.0400",
"BookBa":"123475.0400",
"TotalCredit":"1234567",
"TotalDebit":"0",
"Usage":"5",
"Period":"May 11 2014 to Jul 11 2014",
"Currency":"GBP",
"Applicants":"Angel",
"Signatories":[
  {
     "Name":"Not Available",
     "BVB":"Not Available"
  }
],
"Details":[
  {
     "PTransactionDate":"24-Jul-14",
     "PValueDate":"24-Jul-13",
     "PNarration":"Cash Deposit",
     "PCredit":"0.0000",
     "PDebit":"40003.0000",
     "PBalance":"40003.0000"
  },
  {
     "PTransactionDate":"24-Jul-14",
     "PValueDate":"23-Jul-14",
     "PTest":"Cash Deposit",
     "PCredit":"0.0000",
     "PDebit":"40003.0000",
     "PBalance":"40003.0000"
  },
  {
     "PTransactionDate":"25-Jul-14",
     "PValueDate":"22-Jul-14",
     "PTest":"Cash Deposit",
     "PCredit":"0.0000",
     "PDebit":"40003.0000",
     "PBalance":"40003.0000"
  },
  {
     "PTransactionDate":"25-Jul-14",
     "PValueDate":"21-Jul-14",
     "PTest":"Cash Deposit",
     "PCredit":"0.0000",
     "PDebit":"40003.0000",
     "PBalance":"40003.0000"
  },
  {
     "PTransactionDate":"25-Jul-14",
     "PValueDate":"20-Jul-14",
     "PTest":"Cash Deposit",
     "PCredit":"0.0000",
     "PDebit":"40003.0000",
     "PBalance":"40003.0000"
  }
]
}
```

I need this to show up as

name, status, location, accountcategory, accounttype, availablebal, totalcredit, totaldebit, etc as columns,

with the pcredit, pdebit, pbalance, ptransactiondate, pvaluedate and 'ptest' having new values each row as the JSON file shows

I've managed to put this script below together from stackoverflow, and its outputting a csv file, however what it shows me now is in the csv file has the headers I needed, and also outputs the status, name, etc. However the rest of the json content from ptransactiondate until the end is actually inside the single column 'Details' - how would I get the rest of it (such as pcredit, pdebit, ptransaction, etc' to have their own columns also?

Please see below for my python script - can I have some advise on what to change again please? thanks

```
import csv
import json

with open("BankStatementJSON1.json", "r") as inputFile:  # open json file
    data = json.loads(inputFile.read())  # load json content

with open("testing.csv", "w") as outputFile:  # open csv file
    output = csv.DictWriter(outputFile, data.keys())  # create a writer
    output.writeheader()
    output.writerow(data)
```

Please see image for what my CSV file looks like, and what I need it to look like. 
[view JSON Output images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epkRP.png)

Comment: What have you tried ? There are quite a few questions about exporting nested json data (well actually pythons dicts and lists - your `data` variable is either one or the other), did you read them ? Also, this is actually a rather non-brainer task, all you have to do is iterating over whatever you have in `data` and generate the appropriate python representation (here a list of dicts) from it before you send it to your `DictWriter`.

Comment: PS : when I mean "what have you tried", I'm not talking about the snippet you already posted which doesn't show any effort at solving your current problem (converting your source data structure to the expected one).

Comment: I have over 10,000 json files to import so i am looking for a solution where it applies to any JSON file with the name, not to reiterate the content of each JSON file and the data inside.. As I said, I am new to python, which is why I am asking for help. I am looking for someone to point me in the right direction or an example using my data so I know what to do. thanks for your help.

Comment: You could have ten thousands times more json files to handle that it wouldn't change anything - you will still have to read each file, parse it from json to Python, then parse the "source" Python representation into the expected "output" representation, then write it to your csv. We're still waiting for an example of what you tried for the "parse the source Python representation into the expected output representation"  part.